# Is there a RAID mode that allows files to be on one physical drive of the array?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I am wondering if there is such a thing as a RAID mode (or similar implementation) that allows to physically split up files without redundancy across multiple, differently sized hard drives to form one large array of disk space. What I am looking for is something like disk striping but each individual file is actually stored on one and only one hard drive.

Example:

```
HDD 1 (1TB)  | HHD2 (3TB)
-------------------------
File 1       | File 2
File 3       | File X
File 4       | ...
```

Together, this system appears to the system as one 4TB HDD but adding files will put it on one drive only. Use case: Maximizing space from drives and being able to recover data when disconnecting a drive from the array.

The net effect of this would be to have only one drive where files put themselves in an available spot on one of the disks in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular RAID is based on block/stripe level access. Then means that what you pictured can be done with blocks, but those do not usually match up to files.  (In which case it would be RAID0, striping).

For more information on that see [this question on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

That is not to say that it is not possible, just that all RAID implementation I know off do not offer such a beast based on files. You could always write something yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of RAID is to ensure redundancy in case a drive fails. This is done by striping data across drives with parity. What you want to do would negate the purpose of having RAID and leave your files vulnerable if you were to have a disk failure. If you want your files on a specific drive, you should either use an external drive or if you have empty slots you can add a JBOD drive to use for storage.